# How to implement geometric operations (union, subtract, intersect) on 3D shapes?

Tags: javafx, 3d, mesh, shapes, java-3d

I am missing basic geometric operations (**union, subtract, intersect**) for javafx class `Shape3D`, like they already do exist for the 2D-based `Shape` class or any advanced 3D modeling tool.

Given two generic meshes `Mesh` a and `Mesh` b, how to build programmatically (in javafx, not using external tools like Blender etc. ...) the resulting `Mesh` c for the corresponding operations?

```
TriangleMesh a = new TriangleMesh();
TriangleMesh b = new TriangleMesh();
// ... construct meshes a and b
TriangleMesh c = a.union(a, b);
c = a.subtract(a, b);
c = a.intersect(a, b);
```

Maybe there is already any open source solution out there I can use for javafx?

Comment: Possibly duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/q/28697842/3956070

Comment: thx for the hint, yes it is :-)